# Having the same chart information with two different pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel

Morning Everyone,

I'm trying to create two charts with a pivot table.But I'm having the exact same two charts while the `columnfield` of the chart aren't the same.
I have the same `columnfield` **Evt F** on both **chart** instead of **Evt F** on **chart 1** and **Evt P** on **chart 2**.The pivot tables and chart are on the same sheet **graphe_clos**.

I hope that i was clear enough Thank You for your time and help

Here's the part of the macro where I create the table and charts.

```
Sub tracer ()

Set Table = Cache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=graphe_clos.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Terminator")
Set Table1 = Cache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=graphe_clos.Cells(25, 1), TableName:="Terminator2")
With graphe_clos.Shapes.AddChart(204, xlColumnClustered).Chart
    .ClearToMatchStyle
    .ChartStyle = 257
end with 

With Table.PivotFields("Tranches")
      .Orientation = xlRowField
      .Position = 1
End With

With Table.PivotFields("Evt F")
      .Orientation = xlColumnField
      .Position = 1
      .PivotItems("(blank)").visible = False
End With

With graphe_clos.Shapes.AddChart(204, xlColumnClustered).Chart
    .ClearToMatchStyle
    .ChartStyle = 257
end with 

With Table1.PivotFields("Tranches")
      .Orientation = xlRowField
      .Position = 1
End With

With Table1.PivotFields("Evt P")
      .Orientation = xlColumnField
      .Position = 1
      .PivotItems("(blank)").visible = False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because of same Cache has been used/shared. You can try something like:

```
Set pvtCache = wbSource.PivotCaches.create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=YourDataRngStr) 'data/table range, something like "A1:E100"
Set pvtCache = wbSource.PivotCaches.create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=YourDataRngStr) 'data/table range, something like "A1:E100"
Set Table = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=graphe_clos.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Terminator")
Set Table1 = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=graphe_clos.Cells(25, 1), TableName:="Terminator2")
```

Thanks